# Pandas dataframe: Filter rows based on regex string search

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that has 128 million rows and I need to find an efficient way to filter the rows in this dataframe.

I need to filter all rows that have "foo" in them. "foo" could be in any column but essentially if any row has "foo" then return that row.

I did something like this:

```
final_rows = df[df['col1'].str.contains(string_to_search))] & df[df['col2' ].str.contains(string_to_search))] ..... etc.
```

but this did not work.

I am new to Pandas, so apologies if this is a very basic question.

Comment: I would suggest for this many rows, that you use a list comprehension within Python ... you should get much faster speeds, compared to running the same operation with Pandas string methods

Comment: @sammywemmy : Yes it actually worked much better with list comprehension. I was able to speed it up almost 5x after using the map built-in technique ! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `apply` with `any`

```
m=df[['col1',...]].apply(lambda x : x.str.contains(string_to_search)).any(axis=1)

final_rows=df[m]
```